# Find customers with at least 5 transactions - looking for a tidier way to do this

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with customer transactions:

```
   customer_id  transaction_amount
0          bob                  12
1          bob                  34
2          bob                  56
3          bob                  23
4         mary                  12
5         mary                  34
6         mary                   3
7         mary                  53
8         mary                  23
9         mary                  12
10        mary                   5
11         jim                   2
12         jim                   5
```

I want to find customers with at least 5 transactions.

What I'm doing works, but it looks very messy. It's a very ugly groupby

I groupby `customer_id`, count the `transaction_amount`.

```
df.groupby('customer_id')['transaction_amount'].count()

customer_id
bob     4
jim     2
mary    7
```

Then I create a mask using the same groupby, but I add the filter `>=5` , then get the `index` of the result.

```
mask = (df.groupby('customer_id')['transaction_amount'].count()>=5)

df.groupby('customer_id')['transaction_amount'].count()[mask].index
```

This gives me my result:

```
Index(['mary']
```

Surely there's a tidier way to do this? Two groupbys on top of eachother just feels wrong.

This is an operation I do a lot in work, so I'd like to know if it can be tidier or more "pythonic" I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each row with customer_id is a unique transaction, you don't need groupby at all. You can use `value_counts`

```
s = df['customer_id'].value_counts()
s[s >= 5].index
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid groupby using `pandas.Series.value_counts` for that following way, consider following simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['bob','bob','mary','mary','mary','jim']})
cnt = df.name.value_counts()
morethan3 = list(cnt.where(cnt>=3).dropna().index)
print(morethan3)
```

output

```
['mary']
```

Explanation: `value_counts()` return `pandas.Series` with index being investigated objects and values being number of occurences, I replace all value which are not `>=3` with `NaN` using `.where` then jettison Nan using `.dropna` and finally taking what index remained.